# Using external application.properties file but the one in resource being used by default

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Below is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(name = "spring.config.location", value="file:D:\\application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
public class MyWebAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyWebAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here I want to use the application.properties file in D drive but the one being used by default is of resource folder in my application. How can I override this choice in Spring?

I am not able to find any override option, if there is any please tell.

Comment: Remove the `@PropertySource` and just start your application with `--spring.config.additional-location=file:D:/application.properties` don't shoehorn this into an `@PropertySource`. Nor does this do what you think it does (the name is the name of the propertysource **not** the name of a property).

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to externalize application.properties file for application on production where we just upload the war file and later it gets decompressed. I don't think I would be able to use --spring.config.additional-location=file:D:/application.properties there

Comment: It will always load the one from the classpath, it will load this one in addition to that. Why deploy a war in the first place instead of an embedded container. When deploying you are probably better of using profiles and ship the properties in the war. Additional properties/overrides you can give in the servlet context through the `context.xml` for the web archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **spring.config.additional-location: file:D:\application.properties** in your application.properties.

or,

use below code in your application.yml:

```
spring
  config
    additional-location: file:D:\\application.properties
```